# Managing programs installed on external hard drives

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive

This is probably asked a lot but for some reason I can't find answers on Google.
I have a system with a standard configuration:

1 SSD used as C:\
4 others HDD D:\ E:\ F:\

C:\ has Windows 8.1 which is fine.

Remaining hard drives movies, installed programs (Notepad++,Steam, etc..)
I could split installations across drives.

My question is what if I wanted to upgrade C:\ to Windows 10

Do I need to reinstall all my programs? I'm guessing I need to otherwise it's not in Windows registry. This is a pain too.

And what if I don't need to reinstall all my programs?

Does that mean I could theoretically have  another SSD G:\ with Windows 10 and switch between Win 8 as C:\ and Win 10 as G:\ without having to reinstalling programs?

Crux of it is I don't want to have to reinstall Steam every time I do a clean install of Windows.

Is there a recommended guide I could read on optimal system configuration?

Comment: "Can you please advise on how to set up my system?" - This quesiton isn't on topic here at Superuser.  'Any advise?" - This question isn't on topic here at Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to reinstall all my programs?

Any program that is not compatible with Windows 10 will be be moved to the Program Files directory within **Windows.old**

> I'm guessing I need to otherwise it's not in Windows registry.

Most applications don't even use the registry.

> Does that mean I could theoretically have another SSD G:\ with Windows
>   10 and switch between Win 8 as C:\ and Win 10 as G:\ without having to
>   reinstalling programs?

In theory if you wanted to clone your current drive you could do this.  Considering the only way ***currently*** **to upgrade to Windows 10** is to purchase a retail license, you don't risk breaking the license agreement, by running both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

> Crux of it is I don't want to have to reinstall Steam every time I do
>   a clean install of Windows.

Just copy the directory to an external drive.  On any new system transfer it to the correct location.  Steam will automatically detect which programs are installed.

Comment: Windows registry was a catchall phrase for anything metadata that a clean install may remove.                                                                      No, I don't want to clone an OS. I may want to install Windows on a fresh drive (deliberately not use a VM). 

"Just copy to an external hard drive"  - that's the point. The program is installed on an external hard drive. I want to remove this step (copying and reinstalling) every time a clean install is done

Comment: You might have used it as a "catch all" phrase but it has specific meaning.